# Do I need a transit visa in Dubai?

Tags: transit-visas, dxb, salvadoran-citizens

I'm travelling from Madrid to Brisbane, but I have a 9 hours layover at Dubai Airport. I do not plan to leave the airport, and the connection is with the same airline (Emirates). I'm from El Salvador.

Do I need a transit visa?

Answer (score 4):

You do not need transit visa, however, do consider having one, as 9 hours is a long layover. Dubai airport is nice, you get free wifi and have plenty of window shopping opportunities plus restaurants but I would still consider getting out for that time and have a tour of the city whether it's day or evening time. Transit visas through Emirates website are around $60 and they process the visa within 3-4 working days.

Comment: Can you please post a link to the website where the visa instructions and requirements are posted?

Comment: Have a look at Emirates Visa Services, you can apply for your visa through 'Manage a Booking' section, as far as I remember, you would just need to upload scanned copy of your passport and recent photograph. Here is the link: http://www.emirates.com/english/plan_book/essential_information/visa_passport_information/prearranged_uae_visas.aspx

Comment: @pnuts - you can stretch your time by taking the metro which allows for more sightseeing and stops right at the malls.

Answer (score 2):

When you are transitting within the same terminal 3 with Emirates then you do not require a visa as you won't pass through immigration.

And it seems this is the case for you.

Comment: Emirates in particular is very good at handling UAE visa, even if you need to get one to visit the city to make a good use of those 9 hours.